# Is it correct this reasoning?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

Let $E,F$ be reals vector space. Since

(1) $\dim (E\times F)=\dim E + \dim F$

(2) $\dim\ \text{Hom}(E,F)=\dim E\cdot \dim F$

Given $r>0$ integer, is it true that:
$$\text{Hom}(E\times \stackrel{(r)}{\ldots} \times E,E)=r(\dim E)^2\quad \text{?}$$
Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, since  $\;\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\dim\Hom(F,E)=\dim F\cdot\dim E$.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of $\operatorname{Hom}(F,E)$ is $\dim F\cdot\dim E$. Since $E^r=\underbrace{E\oplus E\oplus\dots\oplus E}_{\text{$r$ times}}$ has dimension $r\dim E$, the result follows.

(The notation $V\oplus W$ is more common than $V\times W$, that's used more frequently in the context of bilinear maps.)

Why is $\dim\operatorname{Hom}(F,E)=\dim F\cdot\dim E$? Represent linear maps with matrices and you'll see.

Why is $\dim\underbrace{E\oplus E\oplus\dots\oplus E}_{\text{$r$ times}}=r\dim E$? By simple induction from $\dim(E\oplus F)=\dim E+\dim F$ that follows from Grassmann's formula.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're pretty much there. What keeps you from thinking this result is right?

Note that, if $E$ is a vector space, then $E \times ... \times E$ is a vector space. Then, for $r > 0$,

$$\dim \left(\hom (E \times \overset{(r)}{\cdots} \times E, E)\right) \underset{(2)}{=} \dim(E \times \overset{(r)}{\cdots} \times E) \times \dim(E) \\ \underset{(1)}{=} \left( \sum_{k=1}^r \dim (E) \right) \times \dim(E) = r(\dim E)^2.$$

Comment: Ok! I have found in some books that *$Hom(E\times\stackrel{(r)}{\ldots} E, E)$ is isomorphic to $\bigotimes_r^1 E$*. From here,we can deduce that $r(\dim E)^2=\dim\bigotimes_r^1E$, right? But $\dim \bigotimes_r^s E=n^{r+1}$! Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @FUUNK1000 The isomorphism you're talking about is wrong.